# Why are observers important in defining rest and motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, observers

Can't we deliberately define an object such as the sun to be at rest and describe all motions relative to it?

Comment: How is that any different from defining an observer?

Comment: Now we could say anything that doesn't change its position w.r.t the sun is at rest and otherwise.

Comment: .... instead of anything that doesn't change its position w.r.t the observer is at rest.

Comment: That would be like choosing the sun as observer which is possible, and one of many choices. However usually you chose the observer so as to make the maths and also the interpretation easier. Say, if you calculate the trajectory if a thrown ball on earth  you likely don't want to do this with respect to the sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user1583209 points out, you can choose any "observer" or frame of reference that you want, including a sun-stationary frame.  But the motions of the planets would then be quite complicated, and would require the introduction of "fictitious forces", that is, "forces" that don't really exist but are necessary to describe the observed motion.  This is because the planets do not orbit around the sun, they orbit around the solar system barycenter (center of mass).  Even the sun itself orbits the barycenter.

The forces are all real, and the motions simpler if a frame of reference is chosen in which Newton's Laws are valid.  Such a frame is an *inertial frame*.  Working in an inertial frame is usually, but not always, easier.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, the question is, what does "observer" mean to you?

To me an "observer" or a "reference frame" is defined as simply a point which we're going to call the "origin" and fix in our coordinate system, and a set of neighboring points that define three orthogonal "coordinate axes," and perhaps a clock to measure time. In other words, an "observer" takes all of these complicated phenomena out in the world and converts them into numbers that we can analyze: this is the sense in which they "observe."

You can certainly have observers who locate, say, the center of the Sun (or even better, the barycenter of the Sun-Jupiter system) as a fixed point in their coordinates. You can even imagine that the fixed point is the origin, so the "observer" is sitting in the center of the Sun. Of course a real observer is not going to be able to do much sitting there, but we can pose it as an ideal abstraction based on what we know about how our instruments assign numbers to the phenomena we see, and how they seem to change as we change observers: even though we can't actually be at the center of the Sun we can say "here is what such a person would see, if they weren't vaporized and crushed and if the Sun were transparent."

And they're important simply because it allows us to define rest and motion in much more quantitative ways, if we can speak of a solid object by defining the position of its center of mass $\vec r(t)$ and perhaps also some vector $\vec \omega(t)$ describing its orientation about that point. Since these are really lists of time-sequences of numbers, we can talk about how the numbers change over time; for example constant motion in a straight line is just $\vec r = \vec r_0 + \vec v~t = [x_0 + v_x~t, y_0 + v_y~t, z_0 + v_z~t].$ All of these are affine transforms of the time coordinate and it's not hard to see that, say, if $v_x \ne 0$ you can write $y(x)$ and $z(x)$ as affine transforms too, which is why we say it's "in a straight line."

Numbers give us something nice to hold on to.